# How do I find the curve for which the area of the triangle formed by a tangent at any point and by the coordinate axes is constant?

Tags: geometry, ordinary-differential-equations

> Find the curve for which the area of the triangle formed by a tangent at any point and by the coordinate axes is constant.

For generic points $(x,y)$ the x intercept $x-\frac{dx}{dy}y$ and the y intercept $-\frac{dy}{dx}x+y$. Hence if these need to be constant we derive the equation:

$$(-xy'+y)(x-y\frac{1}{y'}) = C \rightarrow -x^2y'+2xy-y^2\frac{1}{y'} = C$$

To solve this differential equation, I am tempted to substitute $y' = p$ to get the form:

$$ -x^2p+2xy-y^2\frac{1}{p} = C$$

But differentiating will yield a $2yy'$ term, which is not easily dealt with in a Lagrange form. In general, if I have a lot of $y'$ but can not get it exactly into the form $y = xf(p)+g(p)$ (d'Albembert's form), what substitution should I use?

Comment: Particular solution $y=\frac{C}{4x}$

Comment: The answer is $xy = C$ if anyone wants to try to reverse engineer the solution ....

Comment: Please include the statement of the actual problem (i.e., your title) in the body of the question, as well.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Differentiating your original equation (for constant area) implicitly led me, after a bit of simplification, to the ODE
$$y''=0 \quad\text{or}\quad y^2-x^2y'^2  = 0.$$
The linear case with negative slope is an uninteresting solution. It's simple enough to solve the remaining pair of separable equations:
$$y' = \pm \frac yx,$$
so $\log y = \pm \log x + c$, i.e., $y=Kx$ or $y=K/x$. The linear case doesn't make sense in this problem. The final solution is, indeed, $xy=K$ for any nonzero $K$.

Comment: The original equation is a Clairaut differential equation as mentionned here https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3797346